# How does coffee cause calcium loss in our body?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, bone-biology, calcium

Recently on radio a doctor advices to reduce the consumption of coffee as it leads to calcium loss(as my mother described). My initial response was: How could such thing be possible? What kind of experiment have been done to assure that the coffee is the cause and not something else? But then I found [this](https://americanbonehealth.org/nutrition/bonesense-on-coffee-tea-and-bone-health/) article on internet, though it doesn't go into depth of the topic. So I'm wondering :

- How does coffee cause calcium loss?
- What is the related chemical reaction?
- Does it just happen in intestine or elsewhere in the body?
- What amount of coffee consumption would make it severe?

Answer (score 3):

Caffeine and coffee do not seem to have any significant adverse effect on calcium metabolism. The supposed mechanisms are inhibition of calcium absorption in the intestine and stimulation of calcium excretion in the kidneys.

[Effects of caffeine on bone and the calcium economy (Food and Chemical Toxicology, Journal, 2002)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12204390):

> Caffeine-containing beverage consumption has been reported to be
>   associated with reduced bone mass and increased fracture risk in some,
>   but not most, observational studies. Human physiological studies and
>   controlled balance studies show **a clear but only a very small
>   depressant effect of caffeine itself on intestinal calcium absorption,
>   and no effect on total 24-h urinary calcium excretion.** The
>   epidemiologic studies showing a negative effect may be explained in
>   part by an inverse relationship between consumption of milk and
>   caffeine-containing beverages. **Low calcium intake is clearly linked
>   to skeletal fragility, and it is likely that a high caffeine intake is
>   often a marker for a low calcium intake.** The negative effect of
>   caffeine on calcium absorption is small enough to be fully offset by
>   as little as 1-2 tablespoons of milk. All of the observations
>   implicating caffeine-containing beverages as a risk factor for
>   osteoporosis have been made in populations consuming substantially
>   less than optimal calcium intakes. **There is no evidence that
>   caffeine has any harmful effect on bone status or on the calcium
>   economy in individuals who ingest the currently recommended daily
>   allowances of calcium.**

[The Association between Coffee Consumption and Bone Status in Young Adult Males according to Calcium Intake Level (Clinical Nutrition Research, 2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4967721/):

> This study analyzed and compared the BMD *[bone mineral density]* and
>   bone metabolism markers according to coffee intake in Korean young
>   adult men aged 19-26 years. **No significant associations were found
>   between current coffee consumption level in Korean young men, and bone
>   status and metabolism according to the calcium intake levels.**